# Can we use NSAppTransportSecurity in XCode 6?

Tags: xcode6, ios9, xcode7, ios-9-beta3, app-transport-security

At WWDC 2015, Apple announced “App Transport Security” for iOS 9. For solving SSL error and to bypass App Transport Security, apple has introduced a key NSAppTransportSecurity to be added in info.plist. can we use this key in Xcode 6 itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/):

```
App Transport Security is available on iOS 9.0 or later, and on OS X 10.11 and later.
```

The functionality is only going to be available with iOS 9.0 or MacOS 10.11 or later, but you can certainly drop the key into any Info.plist file compiled into the app.

Comment: I am able to run in ios9 simulator, web services are working fine. So If i am pushing the app to appstore before iOS9 public release, Will Apple reject the build or will web services work once ios9 public version is released?

Comment: I am able to compile the in xcode6 and services are working fine. Please your thoughts.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right.  You can drop pretty much any key into the info.plist file (as long as it's conforms to a string or int or bool type or whatever) and it will compile with Xcode 5, 6, 7, etc.  The actual functionality will only be picked up in iOS 9, though.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to install the ipa created from xcode6.0 in ios9 device and checking whether the services are working or not.